# Live usb version works but not installed version

Tags: drivers, usb

Everything in ubuntu 12.4 works when I boot from a persistent live usb stick, but when I install it, the wireless network driver and mouse don't work. I'm running it on a eee 1000H netbook.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with other wireless adapter and mouse? I had same problem with wireless adapter and that worked for me. Have you tested if it works with the normal cd? I think you should report this as a bug whit or without further tests. And dont forget to add what specs and what mouse and wireless adapter you have!